# Take a user input value and insert it somewhere else in the form before submission?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms

Is is possible to take an input value and insert it somewhere else in the form before submission?

```
<form action="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php" method="post" id="login-form">
    <p>Please login.</p>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="log" id="log" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars(stripslashes($user_login), 1) ?>" />
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="pwd" id="pwd" />
    <p>
        <input name="rememberme" id="rememberme" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="forever" /> Remember me
    </p>
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>/<?php echo $_POST['log']; ?>" />
    <p>
        <a href="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword">Recover password</a>
    </p>                                
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="LOGIN" class="login-button" />                                
</form>
```

I'd like to take the value that the user enters into this input:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Username" name="log" id="log" value="<?php echo wp_specialchars(stripslashes($user_login), 1) ?>" />
```

And put the value into this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>/<?php echo $_POST['log']; ?>" />
```

I'd given it a go by putting in `S_POST['log']` but that doesn't work.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try JQuery to assign the value before submission.

```
// 1. Change the type='submit' to type='button'
// 2. Give new submit button an id, DO NOT USE 'submit' 

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#submits').click(function(event) {

        $('input[name="redirect_to"]').val( $('input[id="log"]').val() ); 
        if( $('input[name="redirect_to"]').val() != '' )
           $('form#login-form').submit();

    });
});
```

Comment: I've just given this a go but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Hi Rob, the code I placed before is just an idea how it works, now I update the code, you can try it now. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use JQuery you could setup a listener like this:

```
$("#log").bind('input', function() {
    $("IDofHiddenField").val("www.domain.com" + $("#log").val());
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to put part of a link in the jquery before the input value? I.e "www.domain.com" (then the jquery part)?

Comment: jquery's val either sets or returns a string, so you can string concat what you're passing with something like:
$("IDofHiddenField").val("www.domain.com/" + $("#log").val());